# Type Mismatch Error, declaring Range Variable in Excel VBA

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, basic

This should be a simple fix, but I've searched and searched and can't figure out what is wrong.

I'm getting a "Run-time Error 13: Type Mismatch":

```
Dim rng As Range    
Dim endRW As Integer, endCol As Integer
endRW = 30
endCol = 10
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,3),Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(endRW,endCol))
```

^^^ the last line is causing the error ^^^^

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(endRW, endCol))
```

Evidence.

[image]

Comment: Then you're doing something different that what I posted. See screenshot. The code works fine.

Comment: Yup you were right. The problem was actually with the MsgBox I was using to find the error, haha. Sorry, thanks for your help.

Comment: Then please accept the answer as explained in the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub temp()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim endRW As Long, endCol As Long
    endRW = 30
    endCol = 10
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(endRW, endCol))
End Sub
```